# keras: insert layers to the beginning (near the input) of an existing model

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I need to add layers to the beginning of an existing model. However, I need to add the layers on "the main model level", that is I can't use the classic functional approach. For example, if I use something like:

```
from keras.layers import Dense,Reshape, Input
inp = Input(shape=(15,))
d1 = Dense(224*224*3, activation='linear')(inp)
r1 = Reshape((224,224,3))
from keras import Model
model_mod = r1(d1)
model_mod = mobilenet(model_mod) 
model_mod = Model(inp, model_mod)
```

I obtain:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         (None, 15)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 150528)            2408448   
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_4 (Reshape)          (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
mobilenet_1.00_224 (Model)   (None, 1000)              4253864
```

So, I obtain a model with a nested *mobilenet_1.00_224 (Model)* submodel. Instead, I would that the nested submodel's layers are "added" after the new top layers (that is, after ``reshape_4'') in form of layers and not of (sub)model. In other terms, would something like:

```
modelB_input = modelB.input
for layer in modelB.layers:
    if layer == modelB_input:
        continue
    modelA.add(layer)
```

This code works for simple sequential models (e.g., vgg, mobilenet) but with more complex models with connections not strictly sequential (e.g., inception,resnet) this code does not work because the layers can not be reconnected using the `add` method of the `sequential` model. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to add model_mod.input as parameter:

```
model_mod = r1(d1)
base_out = mobilenet(model_mod) 
out =Flatten()(base_out)
model_mod = Model(inp, out)
```

Comment: i get ---> `model_mod = Model(inp, model_mod.input) AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'input'`

Comment: I have worked solution with Flatten(), but I can't reproduce exactly your code. So sorry if I didn't help you